# Having trouble connecting to personal Oracle 11g Database via SQL Developer from another computer in my home

Tags: database, oracle11g, dns

computer wizards!  I've searched for several days, and applied multiple solutions I found - but still having this issue.

I have developed a database in **Oracle 11g** using **SQL Developer** on my desktop at home.  I'd like to access that database from my laptop at home, but I'm getting various errors depending on what I try.

I'll refer to my desktop as the **HOST** computer, and my laptop as the **CLIENT** computer.  I believe I have the appropriate client software installed on my laptop (I also have the full **Oracle 11g database** installed on my laptop) - but something is wrong with my listener files or tns files, I'm assuming.  I'm able to ping the **HOST** from the **CLIENT** with no issues - just can't connect to the database.

The relevant details I believe you need to see are below:

```
IP configuration details from the 'HOST' computer:
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::48e8:82ce:a1cb:c4cd%15
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.110
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 13:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::64c6:cc86:259d:3699%12
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.137.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 4:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:953c:2c32:3d76:3049:aa5c
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2c32:3d76:3049:aa5c%13
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
```

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------

`lnsrctl` services from **HOST**:

```
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "D000" established:5 refused:2 current:0 max:1022 state:ready
         DISPATCHER <machine: DIXON-FAMILY-CO, pid: 1764>
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=Dixon-Family-Computer)(PORT=50310))
Service "xe" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
The command completed successfully
##-----------------------------------
```

---

the `TNSnames.ora` details from the **HOST** computer:

```
LISTENER_DBGLOBAL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1523))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1523))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

DBGLOBAL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1523))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = dbglobal)
    )
  )

##----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`TNSnames.ora` from **CLIENT** computer:

```
LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

XE = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Dixon-Family-Computer)(PORT = 1522))
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )
```

`Listener.ora` details from **CLIENT**:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\erika\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\erika\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1522))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Dixon-Family-Computer)(PORT = 1522))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
##-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have tried connecting in to the database from the client machine via **SQL Plus** as well as **SQL Developer**.

I've tried the following - as a TNS and a Basic connection:

```
BUDGET_DATASRC/password@//Dixon-Family-Computer:1522/xe:DEDICATED/XEXDB
BUDGET_DATASRC/password@//Dixon-Family-Computer:50310[I'm not sure which port to use]/xe:DEDICATED/XEXDB
```

Could anyone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?  I've never set up a database connection at home before.  This is strictly for personal family use - and to help me sharpen my skill set.  I'd just like to be able to access the database hosted on my desktop from my laptop as well.

Thank you in advance for taking the time to look at this :)

Regards,
Erika

Answer (score 0):

I was able to identify what I was missing.  I added a DB listener port in my firewall settings on my host computer to allow inbound connections from my client computer.  Now I'm connected to the database with no issues from my client pc.  I spent DAYS working on this - so I hope my question/answer helps somebody!